# Media Element audio player - embed M3U playlist

Tags: html, audio, mediaelement.js

Hi all I'm new to the MediaElement HTML5 player stuff.  I've read through the docs and still doesn't quite work for me.   Here is my head section with the correct imports, I've checked all the relative paths.  Can someone help me out?

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link href="build/mediaelementplayer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();
});
```

and here's my embedded player later on in the html....the first example does NOT work for a playlist.  But the second one works fine for a single file.

```
   <audio src="Music\Demo.m3u" width="320" height="240"></audio>

<audio controls="controls" src="Music/01%20Skies%20and%20Shadows.mp3" id="player"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this plugin as a workaround...

https://github.com/duozersk/mep-feature-playlist